# Pipeline Azure with sonarcloud

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

##[error]No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands: java, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.144.0

ITS MY AGENTE JOB 1

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands: java

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'

- task: SonarSource.sonarcloud.14d9cde6-c1da-4d55-aa01-********.SonarCloudPrepare@1
  displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarCloud'
  inputs:
    SonarCloud: SonarcloudService
    organization: *******
    projectKey: 'playcerbr_********'
    projectName: MyCookBook

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '$(Parameters.TestProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: SonarSource.sonarcloud.ce096e50-6155-4de8-8800-*******.SonarCloudAnalyze@1
  displayName: 'Run Code Analysis'
  inputs:
    jdkversion: 'JAVA_HOME'

- task: SonarSource.sonarcloud.38b27399-a642-40af-bb7d-******.SonarCloudPublish@1
  displayName: 'Publish Quality Gate Result'
```

i am using a self agent by docker on my ubuntu machine

Comment: It's telling you that there are no agents of the appropriate version with a `java` capability defined. What steps have you taken to troubleshoot the issue?